# Was the Robed Engineer a Good Guy?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

I have read many posts here r.e. the Engineers in PROMETHEUS, but what stands out is that the Robed Engineer in the beginning of the movie is SOMETHING DIFFERENT.

The opening scene Engineer is dressed in a Robe, while the other Engineers are dressed in military armor of some kind.  This implies that there are two different factions within the Engineers.

The gist / theory that I got from the movie was:

> The Engineers are divided into two factions - peacemakers and warmongers.  The one in the Robe was a Peacemaker / Priest who sacrificed himself by drinking a heap of the black liquid (or an extra strong dose).  It is implied that if the black liquid cannot cause a transformation successfully then it destroys the host (q.v. the exploding head), and the robed Engineer appears to have ingested enough to completely overwhelm his own system, disintegrating it but causing DNA in the local environment to rapidly mutate and spawn new *DEADLY* life forms.  His apparent (again theorized) goal was to use the Black Liquid against the warmongers, to STOP them from their deadly mission to destroy Earth by sacrificing himself.

I support this idea with the implication that:

> The Engineers who came to Earth were well received and apparently entirely beneficent. This suggests that the one's who seeded Earth may well have been a totally different political faction than the warmongers who seek to destroy Earth, e.g. the standard Hawk v Dove arrangement, or Priest-Scientists v Military, etc. The scene where the Engineers are running for their lives inside the ship implies that they are under attack.  The timeline suggests that it would be from something scarier and / or more unpredictable than themselves, hence the Robed Engineer's monsters appear to have succeeded in destroying most of the warmongers and stopping them from heading to Earth.

QUESTION:
Does this mean the Robed Engineer was on the side of Earth?

Comment: He was at a different point in time. Read this: http://cavalorn.livejournal.com/584135.html

Answer (score 3):

The Lone Engineer at the beginning of Prometheus *was* there to sacrifice himself in order to seed Earth with intelligent life. This is described on the Prometheus Blu-Ray's extras section, in the caption for one of the deleted scenes:

> **Scene 7: Arrival of the Engineers**
>
> The Engineers touch down on prehistoric Earth for a sacred ritual devoted to the seeding of Intelligent life. Whereas the Theatrical version of the scene is devoted to the Lone Sacrifice Engineer, this early cut features several of his comrades, including the Elder Engineer. The ceremony was filmed with dialogue but unsatisfied with the result, Ridley Scott removed the dialogue entirely.

[image: Screen Capture]

However, "Good Guy" is a fairly vague term... while his purpose was to seed Earth, David theorizes that this is how the Engineers work. They create *and* destroy. It is unclear if they created life on Earth and later decided to destroy it, or if their intention was to destroy the life they created from the beginning.